# How can i fadeIn and fadeOut the final information of this program

Tags: javascript, fadein, fadeout

I have to fadeIn and fadeOut the information of the setInterval at the end of the program: I want that after certain amount of time, the information slowly disappear and then reappear after the information slowly. I saw other example of this subject but I didn't find a solution, i don't know how to do it, any suggestion? (Excuse me for my horrible english).

```
var newsTitle = [];
var newsDate = [];
var pubDate = [];
var newsHours = [];
var newsLenght;
var resultDate = [];
var cDate = 0;
var w = 1;
var newsName = "La Repubblica";

function newsUpdateAll() {
    cDate = new Date();
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            extractData(xhttp);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://www.repubblica.it/rss/homepage/rss2.0.xml", true);
    xhttp.send();
}

function extractData(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        newsTitle[i] = x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        pubDate[i] = x[i].getElementsByTagName("pubDate")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var newnewsDate = new Date(pubDate[i]);
        newsDate[i] = ((cDate - newnewsDate)/1000)/60;
    }
    newsLenght = x.lenght;
    newsClassification();
    setRules();
    document.getElementById("news-title").innerHTML = newsTitle[0];
    document.getElementById("news-name").innerHTML = newsName + ", " + newsHours[0];
}

function newsClassification() {
    var length = newsDate.length;
    for (var i = (length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        for (var j = (length - i); j > 0; j--) {
            if(newsDate[j] < newsDate[j-1]) {
                var tmp = newsDate[j];
                newsDate[j] = newsDate[j-1];
                newsDate[j-1] = tmp;
                var tmp2 = newsTitle[j];
                newsTitle[j] = newsTitle[j-1];
                newsTitle[j-1] = tmp2;
            }
        }        
    }
}

function setRules(){
    for (i = 0; i < newsDate.length; i++) {
        resultDate[i] = Math.round(newsDate[i]);
        if (resultDate[i] >= 1440){
            newsHours[i] = Math.round((resultDate[i] / 60) / 24);
            if (newsHours[i] > 1){
                newsHours[i] = newsHours[i] + " giorni fa:";
            }else{
                newsHours[i] = newsHours[i] + " giorno fa:";
            }
        }else if (resultDate[i] >= 60){
            newsHours[i] = Math.round(resultDate[i] / 60);
            if (newsHours[i] > 1){
                newsHours[i] = newsHours[i] + " ore fa:";
            }else{
                newsHours[i] = newsHours[i] + " ora fa:";
            }
        }else{
            newsHours[i] = resultDate[i];
            if (newsHours[i] > 1){
                newsHours[i] = newsHours[i] + " minuti fa:";
            }else{
                newsHours[i] = newsHours[i] + " minuto fa:";
            }
        }
    }
}

newsUpdateAll();

setInterval(function (){
    if (w > 55){
        w = 1;
        newsUpdateAll();
    }
    document.getElementById("news-title").innerHTML = newsTitle[w];
    document.getElementById("news-name").innerHTML = newsName + ", " + newsHours[w];
    w++;
},20000);
```

Comment: you spelled `lenght` wrong. you tried to do `x.lenght` which isn't defined. That's one possible reason the code you showed isn't working.

Comment: Do you get any errors at your console??

Comment: The code works perfectly, but I want to add to it the "fade in" "fade out" of the information of "document.getElementById("news-title").innerHTML = newsTitle[w];
    document.getElementById("news-name").innerHTML = newsName + ", " + newsHours[w];"